# how long the map call can last?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I want to do some heavy processing in the map() call of the mapper.
I was going through the source file MapReduceServlet.java:

```
// Amount of time to spend on actual map() calls per task execution.
public static final int PROCESSING_TIME_PER_TASK_MS = 10000;
```

Does it mean, the map call can last only for 10secs.  What happens after 10sec?
Can I increase this to large number like 1min or 10min.

-Aswath

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce operations are executed in tasks using [Push Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Quotas_and_Limits_for_Push_Queues), and as said in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Task_Execution) the task deadline is currently 10 minutes (limit after which you will get a `DeadlineExceededException`).

If the task failed to execute, by default App Engine retries it until it succeed. If you need longer deadline that 10 minutes, you can use [Backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Push_Queues_and_Backends) for executing your tasks.

Looking at the actual usage of PROCESSING_TIME_PER_TASK_MS in [Worker.java](http://code.google.com/searchframe#XwsseYUY0Ps/trunk/java/src/com/google/appengine/tools/mapreduce/v2/impl/handlers/Worker.java&q=PROCESSING_TIME_PER_TASK_MS%20package%3ahttp://appengine-mapreduce%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=108), this value is used to limit the number of map call done in a single task.

After each `map` call has been executed if more than 10s has elapsed since the beginning of the task, it will spawn a new task to handle the rest of the map calls.

1. [`Worker.scheduleWorker`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#XwsseYUY0Ps/trunk/java/src/com/google/appengine/tools/mapreduce/v2/impl/handlers/Worker.java&q=PROCESSING_TIME_PER_TASK_MS%20package%3ahttp://appengine-mapreduce%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=51) spawns a new Task for a each given shard
2. Each task will call [`Worker.processMapper`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#XwsseYUY0Ps/trunk/java/src/com/google/appengine/tools/mapreduce/v2/impl/handlers/Worker.java&q=PROCESSING_TIME_PER_TASK_MS%20package%3ahttp://appengine-mapreduce%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=81)
3. `processMapper` execute 1 `map` call
4. if less than PROCESSING_TIME_PER_TASK_MS have elapsed since 2. go back to 3.
5. else if processing is not finished [reschedule a new worker task](http://code.google.com/searchframe#XwsseYUY0Ps/trunk/java/src/com/google/appengine/tools/mapreduce/v2/impl/handlers/Worker.java&q=PROCESSING_TIME_PER_TASK_MS%20package%3ahttp://appengine-mapreduce%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=303)

In the worst case scenario the default task request deadline (10 minutes) should apply to each of your individual map call.

Comment: File MapReduceServlet.java
// Amount of time to spend on actual map() calls per task execution. public static final int PROCESSING_TIME_PER_TASK_MS = 10000.   Is this placing a limit on the map() call, even if the task is allowed 10min.

Comment: What is the relation between appengine task and map()?  Does a map() call is executing as the task?  Or a task is calling the map()?